# Are there any pre-commit linters that can stop me from committing code with PySnooper decorators?

Tags: python, pre-commit

I use PySnooper library for debugging.
It looks like this:

```
import pysnooper

@pysnooper.snoop()
def number_to_bits(number):
    ...
```

I don't want to commit such a code. This @pysnooper library is for debugging only. How to prevent it with pre-commit hooks?

Comment: Questions asking fro software or library recommendations are off-topic here. That said, look into https://pre-commit.com, you can add your own checks and there's a bunch of pre-made checks for everything from ssh keys to file name case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/adamchainz/flake8-tidy-imports#banned-modules
This linter can do it.

```
[flake8]
banned-modules = pysnooper = remove debugging code!
```